How to add dynamic filter to visualization in Superset?
I want to add a filter for table visualization that will filter by the last month, taking into account the main filter applied to the entire dashboard.
For example, if there no filter I want see measure for this month 2024-07.
If filter for all dashboard set to <= 2024-06, I want see measure value for last month 2024-06 and so on.
It's really easy to achieve in Power BI, but I can't do it in Superset.
